# Broken Images in Flex Project

Tags: apache-flex, air, mxml

I'm trying to get an old Flex project up and running.  (It was written by someone else, in Flash Builder.  I've imported it into FDT).

I've noticed that all my MXML image links are all broken.

I thought I could remedy this by adding the assets directory to the package contents.  (Project Properties -> FDT AIR Properties -> Desktop ... added the assets directory)  But it didn't help.

I found a work-around.  I simply say:

```
<mx:Image source="@Embed('assets/picture.png')"
```

Instead of:

```
<mx:Image source="assets/picture.png"
```

I also tried /assets, /src/assets, ../assets/, /..assets/ etc... (by the way, assets is a subdirectory of src)

But I'm curious why adding the assets directory to the package didn't work.  And given that the project must have worked before as-is - I'd like to make it work for me, without modification.

Answer (score 0):

Ive found that diff IDEs have their own "opinions" on how these assets paths are interpreted. Same experience when I moved from FB to IntelliJ.

Comment: Actually, I did have to add a leading "/" at the front in the AS3.

[Embed(source="/assets/picture.png")]

But I tried several paths in the MXML, and none worked.